# I'm attempting to determine my user's role from within a view helper and am concerned that I'm doing it wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have helpers that are used to determine whether a given user is an administrator or a vendor. From within the helpers, I query the database for their respective role objects (administrator, vendor, etc.) for comparison against roles associated with the user but have a feeling that this is an ass-backward way to go about determine a user's role.

**Am I doing something wrong here? What could I do better? I should probably mention that I'm using/learning Pundit, so maybe it contains a better means by which to accomplish this.**

Here's my code:

users_helper.rb

```
 1 module UsersHelper
  2   def admin?
  3     # Determine whether the user has administrator status within a given event
  4     @admin_role = Role.find(1)
  5     return true if @user.roles.include? @admin_role
  6   end
  7
  8   def vendor?
  9     # Determine whether the user is an approved vendor within a given event
 10     @vendor_role = Role.find(2)
 11     return true if @user.roles.include? @vendor_role
 12   end
 13 end
```

Here's how I use the helpers from within my template:

show.html.erb

```
  1 <% provide(:title, @user.username) %>
  2
  3 <% if admin?  %>
  4   <p>Admin</p>
  5 <% elsif vendor? %>
  6   <p>Vendor</p>
  7 <% else %>
  8   Something else.
  9 <% end  %>
```

Comment: try this [https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model] and [https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization]. hope it helps

Comment: @Sontya, CanCan is not maintained

Comment: wrong is a strong word. You may find that you are querying when you don't need to etc. But your way "works". I would suggest caching the roles so you are only loading them from the db once. But if it is a low volume application and not an issue, you can always address it later.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, `include?` method returns boolean, so:

```
return true if @user.roles.include? @admin_role
```

is equal to:

```
@user.roles.include? @admin_role
```

Unless you need `nil` instead of `false`.

Second, your method names and the code itself should be so simple and self-descriptive, to not require comments. Unless you need automated documentation, when writing public gem or something.

Regarding you question, IMHO you should do this in your User model:

```
def admin?
  roles.where(id: 1).any?
end
```

Then you can do `@user.admin?` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The associations of User model with roles  imply that your User model may have more then one role such as admin or vendor at the same time.

I would suggest to refactor User model to use has_one association with role, so that users will have only one role.

Then the helper in user_helper.rb might be something like:

```
def is_a?(user)
  roles  = { Roles.find(1) => "Admin", Roles.find(2) => "Vendor"}
  roles.fetch(user.role) do
      "Something else."
  end
```

end

This will return string with correct string definition of role.  You can make comparison with that or use it in view as follows:

```
<p><%= is_a?(@role) %></p>
```

Which does same thing as your code above in one line.

Answer (score 0):

This might be better over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

1) Your role implementation is a bit clunky (what with the magic numbers) - do you do anything with the Role class that warrants its being an ActiveRecord class?
If not, you could use [the role_model gem](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) (as mentioned by Sontya), which saves the user roles as a bitmask in the users table.
In case you need a more sophisticated role class, you may want to have a look at [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify), which is similar in concept to your current solution.

Either way, user roles in Rails applications are a solved problem, you do not need to write your own solution (of course, don't let that discourage you, building your own solution is at the very least a good learning exercise).

2) Checking for roles in a view is a pretty bad idea, especially if you're already using pundit.

If you ever add a new role, you need to go through all the views and change the if conditions to support the new new role.
This is a problem that explodes when both your number of views and your number of roles grow.

Instead, use the pundit policies in your view, and check for the users role(s) in the corresponding policy object.

Example:

```
class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def delete?
    user.is?(:admin)
  end
end
```

in the view:

```
<% if policy(@company).delete? %>
  delete link here
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to authorize in the controller as well!

That way, if you add a new role, you simply have to change a few policy objects and you're good to go.

Comment: role_model link has extra ']' character